# Building a todo app in React, used filters but need a way to make sure "complete" button only removes one task instead of two

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, filter, jsx

I'm new to learning react so I followed this tutorial  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_components to create a todo app and then tweaked it to fit the requirements of the project I'm working on. Everything works the way it should except when I delete (complete) things from the associate side, it also deletes it from my main side as well. I understand the general concept of why that's happening (I don't have two separate lists in my code), just not sure how to go about fixing it without removing the filter I have in place. I had tried to implement a separate list for those tasks but just wasn't understanding how to go about it.

Added CodeSandBox for more context: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-sky-5f482?file=/src/index.js
Check task items and then view the items you've checked in "Show Associate Tasks." The issue is completing a task on the associate side also completes it on the "Show All Tasks" side.

App.js

```
const FILTER_MAP = {
  All: () => true,
  Associate: task => task.checked 
};
const FILTER_NAMES = Object.keys(FILTER_MAP);

function App(props) {

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(props.tasks);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('All');

  function toggleTaskChecked(id) {
    const updatedTasks = tasks.map(task => {
      if (id === task.id) {
        return {...task, checked: !task.checked}
      }
      return task;
    });
    setTasks(updatedTasks);
  }

  function completeTask(id) {
    const remainingTasks = tasks.filter(task => id !== task.id);
    setTasks(remainingTasks);
  }

  const taskList = tasks
    .filter(FILTER_MAP[filter])
    .map(task => (
      <Todo
        id={task.id}
        name={task.name}
        checked={task.checked}
        key={task.id}
        toggleTaskChecked={toggleTaskChecked}
        completeTask={completeTask}
      />
    ));

  const filterList = FILTER_NAMES.map(name => (
    <FilterButton
    key={name}
    name={name}
    isPressed={name === filter}
    setFilter={setFilter}
  />
  ));

  function addTask(name) {
    const newTask = { id: "todo-" + nanoid(), name: name, checked: false };
    setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1 className = "tasks-header">Task Tracker</h1>
      <Form addTask={addTask}/>
      <div className="list-buttons">
        {filterList}
      </div>
      <ul
        role="list"
        className="todo-list"
        aria-labelledby="list-heading"
      >
        {taskList}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App
```

Todo.js

```
export default function Todo(props) {

  return (
    <li className="todo stack-small">
      <div className="c-cb">
        <input id={props.id} 
        type="checkbox" 
        defaultChecked={props.checked}
        onChange={() => props.toggleTaskChecked(props.id)} 
        />
        <label className="todo-label" htmlFor="todo-0">
          {props.name}
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="btn-group">
        <button type="button" 
        className="complete-button"
        onClick={() => props.completeTask(props.id)}
        >
          Complete 
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
  }
```

index.js

```
const DATA = [
  { id: "todo-0", name: "Brush Teeth", checked: false },
  { id: "todo-1", name: "Make Dinner", checked: false },
  { id: "todo-2", name: "Walk Dog", checked: false },
  { id: "todo-3", name: "Run Reports", checked: false },
  { id: "todo-4", name: "Visit Mom", checked: false },
  { id: "todo-5", name: "Aerobics", checked: false },
  { id: "todo-6", name: "Project", checked: false },
  { id: "todo-7", name: "Lecture", checked: false },
  { id: "todo-8", name: "Have Lunch", checked: false }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App tasks={DATA}/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

FilterButton.js

```
function FilterButton(props) {
    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        className="toggle-btn"
        aria-pressed={props.isPressed}
        onClick={() => props.setFilter(props.name)}
      >
        <span className="visually-hidden">Show </span>
        <span>{props.name}</span>
        <span className="visually-hidden"> Tasks</span>
      </button>
    );
  }

export default FilterButton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 3 boolean fields: `checked`, `completed`, `completedAssoc`.

```js
  {
    id: "todo-0",
    name: "Brush Teeth",
    checked: false,
    completed: false,
    completedAssoc: false
  },
```

The filters will work as follows:

```js
  const FILTER_MAP = {
    All: (task) => !task.completed,
    Associate: (task) => task.checked && !task.completedAssoc
  };
```

And finally changes in `completeTask` and `addTask`:

```js
  function completeTask(id) {
    const complField = filter === "All" ? "completed" : "completedAssoc";
    const updatedTasks = tasks.map((task) =>
      id === task.id ? { ...task, [complField]: true } : task
    );
    setTasks(updatedTasks);
  }

  function addTask(name) {
    const newTask = {
      id: "todo-" + nanoid(),
      name: name,
      checked: false,
      completed: false,
      completedAssoc: false
    };
    setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
  }
```

Comment: Just updated the Associate filter

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood, sorry I didn't explain that very well. There's all the general tasks you can add to your todo list (the data from index.js) lets say, and you would check the ones you want to add a copy of to the "associate's list," but they should be able to be completed separately. Clicking the complete button should remove it from the corresponding list and leave it on the other. I was given a link for spread operators, but I'm not sure how to apply that with what I've done here with just filtering out the checked tasks into the associate side.

Comment: Thank you for more details. So as I understand, we need to have 2 separate lists for All and Associates. And when the checkbox is clicked, it copies the task, and then it appears on the second list. After that if task is completed on Associates list, it is not completed on All, and vice versa? Also, what if we click checkbox on All list and then unclick it on Associates? Will it remove from the Associates? Should the associates list have the checkbox at all?

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I meant. So your solution you posted actually worked exactly how I needed, but removed the "complete" functionality from the main list (the button just clicks now but doesn't remove the task). The checkbox works both ways, so you can add it to the associates side but also use either lists checkbox to remove it from the associate side.

Comment: Ok, I hope I got it finally) It came to my mind that another solution would be to have 3 boolean properties in the array. That actually sound more straight forward to me, will give it a try...

Comment: @lrl12345 update the code, please check it.